# Getting compile exception inside ActionFilter when accessing Request Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this little bit of code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class SecureFilter : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (null == filterContext)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (null != filterContext.HttpContext && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Where I am trying to determine if the request is local or not is where I am getting the compile time exception.  It gives me this error:

> 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and no extension method 'Request' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

From what I understand the Request object actually belongs to the controller, but I am not quite sure how I am supposed to create this action filter if I am not able to gain access to the object.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Josh, this must be a configuration issue - your code snippet is working fine for me. If you start a brand new MVC project, do you get the same problem?

Comment: @Nick Riggs, Ok very strange.  Adding the action filter to the primary project works.  Created a new mvc solution and added the filter to a different project and it worked as well.  So something is screwy with my project, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Just a thought, could it be some extention method that requires a using statement you may have removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was something quirky with the project it seems.  I followed Nick Riggs advice and tried a test solution and it worked just fine.  So I deleted the project from my current solution and created a new one and just copied the files into it.  This got it working.

Answer (score 1):

@Josh, I'd like to say that it's just because of System.Web.Abstractions assembly reference. May be you removed the reference inadvertently.